# Как привязать TitleBar к коду?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, framelesswindowhint

Мой основной код:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import os
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://objection.lol"))
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('objection.png'))
        
    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle(title)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("objection.lol")
app.setOrganizationName("objection.lol")
app.setOrganizationDomain("objection.lol")

window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Мой код **titlebar**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_tbWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, tbWidget):
        tbWidget.setObjectName("tbWidget")
        tbWidget.resize(600, 40)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tbWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        tbWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        tbWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        tbWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(tbWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tbWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(tbWidget)
        self.tbWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget#tbWidget_2{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(12, 11, 16);\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_2.setObjectName("tbWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tbWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setObjectName("tbWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.tbLabel_6 = MovableLabel(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbLabel_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 5))
        self.tbLabel_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 5))
        self.tbLabel_6.setText("")
        self.tbLabel_6.setObjectName("tbLabel_6")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tbLabel_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\n"
"    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border-radius:1px;\n"
"    font-size:18px;\n"
"    font-family:dripicons-v2;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(49, 48, 53);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#tbPushButton_3:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(232, 17, 35);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_3.setObjectName("tbWidget_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tbPushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setObjectName("tbPushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.tbPushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font-size:13px;")
        self.tbPushButton_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.tbPushButton_2.setObjectName("tbPushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tbPushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton.setObjectName("tbPushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tbLabel = MovableLabel(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 10))
        self.tbLabel.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 10))
        self.tbLabel.setText("")
        self.tbLabel.setObjectName("tbLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbLabel, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tbWidget_2)

        self.retranslateUi(tbWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(tbWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, tbWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        tbWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("tbWidget", "Form"))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "╳"))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setText(_translate("tbWidget", ""))
```

мне нужно, чтобы за место обычной **title bar**

[image: обычная title bar]

была моя: [image: моя title bar]

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_tbWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, tbWidget):
        tbWidget.setObjectName("tbWidget")
        tbWidget.resize(600, 40)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tbWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        tbWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        tbWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        tbWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(tbWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.tbWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(tbWidget)
        self.tbWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget#tbWidget_2{\n"
"    background-color: #3FA796;\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_2.setObjectName("tbWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tbWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.tbWidget_5.setObjectName("tbWidget_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
# ??? ----------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvv
# ???        self.tbLabel_6 = MovableLabel(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbLabel_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel('tbLabel_6', self.tbWidget_5,
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)        
#        self.tbLabel_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 5))
#        self.tbLabel_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 5))
#        self.tbLabel_6.setText("")
        self.tbLabel_6.setObjectName("tbLabel_6")
        self.tbLabel_6.setStyleSheet(
            "#tbLabel_6 {color: #FEC260; font-size: 22px;}")
       
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tbLabel_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_5)
        self.tbWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tbWidget_2)
        self.tbWidget_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 40))
        self.tbWidget_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\n"
"    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border-radius:1px;\n"
"    font-size:18px;\n"
"    font-family:dripicons-v2;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(49, 48, 53);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#tbPushButton_3:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(232, 17, 35);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    padding-top:5px;\n"
"    padding-left:5px;\n"
"}")
        self.tbWidget_3.setObjectName("tbWidget_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tbPushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setObjectName("tbPushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.tbPushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font-size:13px;")
        self.tbPushButton_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.tbPushButton_2.setObjectName("tbPushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tbPushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbPushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.tbPushButton.setObjectName("tbPushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbPushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        ''' ???
# ???        self.tbLabel = MovableLabel(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.tbLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('tbLabel', self.tbWidget_3)          
        
        self.tbLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 10))
        self.tbLabel.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 10))
#        self.tbLabel.setText("")
        self.tbLabel.setObjectName("tbLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tbLabel, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        '''
        
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tbWidget_2)

        self.retranslateUi(tbWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(tbWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, tbWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        tbWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("tbWidget", "Form"))
        self.tbPushButton_3.setText(_translate("tbWidget", "╳"))
        self.tbPushButton_2.setText(_translate("tbWidget", ""))
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class TitleBar(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_tbWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
  
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                     # +++
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                    # +++

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://objection.lol"))
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
#-        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('objection.png'))
# !!! +++
        self.titleBar = TitleBar()                                   # !!! +++
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)           # +++
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)                        # +++
        layout.setSpacing(0)                                         # +++
        layout.addWidget(self.titleBar)                              # +++
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)                               # +++
        
    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle(title)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема в том, что его никак не передвинуть, пусть и решение правильное, если есть возможность, помогите.

Comment: @Alord если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос и вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: хорошо... спасибо @S. Nick